# Syntax Error: cannot assign to function call

Tags: python

I got this error in Python while I was coding:
`SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call.` 
This is my code:

```py
for number in range(1,101):
    if int(number) % 3 == 0 and int(number) % 5 == 0:
        int(number) = “fizzbuzz”
    if int(number) % 3 == 0:
        int(number) = “fizz”
    if int(number) % 5 == 0:
        int(number) = “buzz”
print(int(number))
```

Can anyone explain what's going wrong?

Comment: What do you expect `int(number) = “fizzbuzz”` to do?

Comment: Well, I expect it would change number into the word “fizzbuzz”.

Comment: It won't work that way because of the reasons explained in the answer below, but this is not the best way to approach this problem anyway. It is bad practice to modify a loop variable as it might have unexpected side effects. You could have simply printed the string `"fizzbuzz"` inside the `if` clause instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, `int()` is used to convert a number string to an integer:

```py
print(int('25') + 5)
```

The above code will output 30 as 25 gets converted to an integer data type and then python sums the two numbers.

If I understand correctly your goal (a bit hard since you didn't specify it), the code below should be what you are looking for:

```py
for number in range(1, 101):
    # if number is divisible by 3
    if number % 3 == 0:
        # if at the same time number is divisible by 5
        if number % 5 == 0:
            print('fizzbuzz')
        # else -> means it's only divisible by 3 and not 5
        else:
            print('fizz')
    # else if divisible by 5 (and not 3)
    elif number % 5 == 0:
        print('buzz')
    # if it's not divisible by either, print the number
    else:
        print(number)
```

This code will print "fizzbuzz" if `number` is divisible by both 3 and 5, "fizz" if it's just divisible by 3, and "buzz" if it's just divisible by 5.

Below is a cleaner version of the code if you realize that a number being divisible by 3 and 5 means it is divisible by 15 (3*5).

```py
for number in range(1, 101):
    if number % 15 == 0:
        print('fizzbuzz')
    elif number % 3 == 0:
        print('fizz')
    elif number % 5 == 0:
        print('buzz')
    else:
        print(number)
```

Comment: This is the famous "fizzbuzz" question. It should also print the number itself if it is not divisible by either 3 or 5.

Comment: @Selcuk added the case you mentioned. I actually had never heard of this fizzbuzz question so thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Note that the second version in your answer won't work because the last `elif` will never trigger. That's (almost) the main trick of the fizzbuzz task.

Comment: @Selcuk Indeed! Thanks for bringing it up - changed the order of the conditions to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`int()` is a function, it takes in an input, and it gives an output. What you are trying to do is to assign a value to that function, not the actual `number` variable. This is giving you an error because functions don't hold values, they hold blocks of code. Variables, however, do hold values (that's what they're for) so you can assign (give a value) to the `number` variable and everything will be fine.

Try replacing `int(number) = ""fizzbuzz"` with `number = "fizzbuzz"`. This will change he value of number itself, and won't try to alter the int function. Most importantly, remember `int()` is a function, not a variable, so you can't give it a value.

I hope this helped!

Comment: Note that this will not be sufficient to fix the code because of the final `print(int(number))` line.

Comment: True, you should end it in ```print(number)``` instead, otherwise it will try to change ```"fizzbuzz"``` into an integer